# Compare two (potentially) undef variables in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to compare two variables in which are usually strings. These variables are generated from a database, `$var1` from one db and `$var2` from another.
When I compare them in a loop I use the `ne` operator. However there are times when I these variables are `null` or `undef`. The comparison is done as follows:

```
foreach my $var1 (@$varlist)
{
  if ($var1 ne $var2)
  {
    print "vars are not equal";
  }
}
```

The issue is that if `$var1` or `$var2` are `undef` then I get an error. However, I need to be able to compare then values as undef b/c I will have to write them. I considered converting the variables to a string 'NULL' and then back but that seemed inefficient.

Any way to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if they are defined, too:

```
foreach my $var1 (@$varlist)
    if ( ! defined $var1 || ! defined $var2 || $var1 ne $var2 )
        print "vars are not equal";
```

This prints that they're not equal if both are undefined. If you want another behaviour, just change the `if` expression.

Comment: Why wouldn't that print the expression if just `$var1` is not defined?

Comment: This was more the basis for my answer which is why I selected it. The final answer looked like this:
`unless ((!defined $var1 && !defined $var2) && (defined $var1 && defined $var2 && $var1 eq $var2))`

Comment: A shorter version using xor: `if ((defined $var1 xor defined $var2) or $var1 ne $var2)`

Comment: @StefanMajewsky This solution will end up comparing two undefined values as strings and thus raise a warning.

Comment: @Prateek your comment has a `&&` where there should be a `||`. It should be: `unless ((!defined $var1 && !defined $var2) || (defined $var1 && defined $var2 && $var1 eq $var2))`

Answer (score 9):

It's not an error to compare undefined values, it's just a warning. I like using Perl's `//` operator (requires >=v5.10) in cases like this to ensure the operators are defined:

```
if (($var1 // '') ne ($var2 // '')) { ... }
```

will treat an undefined string as the empty string during the comparison, for example.

Since you want the operands to have a specific value when they are printed (`NULL` was one possibility), you could also consider using the `//=` operator.

```
if (($var1 //= 'NULL') ne ($var2 //= 'NULL')) {
   print "$var1 and $var2 are not equal";
}
```

will use the value of `$var1` or `$var2`, or `'NULL'` if they are undefined, in the comparison.

Comment: I like this concept, and will use it somewhere else, but it was not specifically what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are practicing safe Perl by using `use warnings;` but now you may have come to the point where you selectively turn them off. These warnings are for your own protection, however if you know that you are going to be comparing possibly undef strings, just turn them off for a little bit (the `no` command is local to the enclosing block, so they turn back on).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $var1 (@$varlist)
{
  no warnings 'uninitialized';
  if ($var1 ne $var2)
  {
    print "vars are not equal";
  }
}
```

Comment: One caveat with this advice is that a string comparison of undef and and empty string will return true - which may or may not be what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the defined function to determine this:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html